# Word-wrap in flexbox is not respecting 100% width limit

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have 2 flexboxes and a flexbox inside one.
I want the text to break into multiple lines if it is bigger than it's parent. For some reason it works if I sent a fixed value (e.g. 250px) as width. If I set the width to 100%, it will not break into multiple lines.

This is the code I have:

```css
#flexparent {
  display: flex
}

#flexchild1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#flexchild2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column
}

#flexchild3 {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexparent">
      <div id="flexchild1">
        FLEXCHILD1
      </div>
      <div id="flexchild2">
        FLEXCHILD2
        <div id="flexchild3">
 ThisisasuperlongsentenceLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtstLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtst
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is how I want it but without the spaces in the long sentence.

```css
#flexparent {
  display: flex
}

#flexchild1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#flexchild2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column
}

#flexchild3 {
  background-color: purple;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexparent">
      <div id="flexchild1">
        FLEXCHILD1
      </div>
      <div id="flexchild2">
        FLEXCHILD2
        <div id="flexchild3">
 Thisisasuperlongsentence Loremipsum dolorsitametcon secteturadipisicingelitAsperi   resnecessitatibusneu eodioImpeditistenes ciuntescorru ptiessecumrepudia ndaequidolor umIllumtempori busquoerrorcumqu eeximpeditmagnam Lore mipsumdo lorsitam etconsecteturadipisicing elitAsperioresne cessitatibusneueodi oImpeditisten esciuntescorruptiessecumrepudia ndaequidolorumIll umtemporibusq uoerrorc umqueeximpe ditmagn amtstLoremipsu mdolorsitametcon secteturadipisici ngelitAsperio resnecessitati busn 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the codepens I made for this.

- The code I have: https://codepen.io/tomzz/pen/mpJMow
- How I want it but without the 250px width: https://codepen.io/tomzz/pen/VyLMaW
- How I want it but without the spaces in the sentence: https://codepen.io/tomzz/pen/vpOeJp

Comment: `width: 100%` has to go on `#flexparent`, not on `#flexchild3`, there is no `width: 100%` on a child when the parent is allowed to grow (`flex: 1` on `#flexchild2`) to infinity.

Comment: You just need to add `min-width: 0` to `#flexchild2`, as indicated below by @LGSon. Here's a complete explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: add word-break:break-all to your first snippet , right after or instead word-wrap ... and see it working . At least in FF.  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qpdVLL

Comment: @LGSon  not sure that the min-width is the one thing here (and duplicate) : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qpdVLL It has to do with the layout somehow but also on the rule used . here you may just need word-break.

Comment: @G-Cyr The downside with `word-break:break-all;` is that it also break the words improper, which i.a. happens in Chrome, and as the issue here is actually the _implied minimum size_, the best is to solve it the proper way.

Answer (score 10):

This is a *min-width* issue, where a flex item can't be smaller than its content.

The default value of `min-width` is `auto`, and in this case it happens to the flex item `#flexchild2`

Give it `min-width: 0` and it will work.

Also, the `width: 100%` is not needed, since a flex "column" item's `align-items` default to `stretch`, and as such automatically take full width of its parent, and can be removed.

Stack snippet

```css
#flexparent {
  display: flex
}

#flexchild1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#flexchild2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-width: 0;                   /*  added  */
}

#flexchild3 {
  background-color: purple;
  /*width: 100%;                      removed  */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexparent">
      <div id="flexchild1">
        FLEXCHILD1
      </div>
      <div id="flexchild2">
        FLEXCHILD2
        <div id="flexchild3">
 ThisisasuperlongsentenceLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtstLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtst
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that percentage-based widths are based off of the immediate parent. If the immediate parent has no `width`, the child cannot know what `100%` of an arbitrary value is. `flex: 1` is shorthand that contains `flex-grow: 1`, meaning that `#flex2` can grow infinitly without setting this `width` constraint.

Percentage-based widths bubble up to the point a fixed `width` is known, so all you have to do is set a `width` of `100%` of `#flexchild2` as well in order for `#flexchild3` to inherit the width of `#flexparent`:

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#flexparent {
  display: flex;
}

#flexchild1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#flexchild2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
}

#flexchild3 {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexparent">
      <div id="flexchild1">
        FLEXCHILD1
      </div>
      <div id="flexchild2">
        FLEXCHILD2
        <div id="flexchild3">
 ThisisasuperlongsentenceLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtstLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtst
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, note that due to you using two columns, you'll probably want to give `#flexparent` a `width` of `100%`, and set your two columns to `20%` and `80%` respectively. Note that `#flexchild3` still inherits `100%` of the `width` of `#flexchild2` (which is `80%` of the `width` of `#flexparent`):

```css
#flexparent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#flexchild1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
}

#flexchild2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 80%;
}

#flexchild3 {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexparent">
      <div id="flexchild1">
        FLEXCHILD1
      </div>
      <div id="flexchild2">
        FLEXCHILD2
        <div id="flexchild3">
 ThisisasuperlongsentenceLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtstLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitAsperioresnecessitatibusneueodioImpeditistenesciuntescorruptiessecumrepudiandaequidolorumIllumtemporibusquoerrorcumqueeximpeditmagnamtst
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Percentage based width does not suffer from the same issue height based does, and as you can see in this fiddle - [https://jsfiddle.net/58cqrLw0/](https://jsfiddle.net/58cqrLw0/) - e.g. `width: 50%` works just fine.

Comment: Also worth checking this isn't set white-space: nowrap;